# Mutiple tables with different width

Tags: tables

I have some tables in a document, but they have different width, so it does not look cool. I would like that all the tables had the same width.

The code of the tables:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | }
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{UC17. Eliminar taxonomía} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Objetivo} & Eliminar taxonomía y guardar cambio en la base de datos \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Actor} & Usuario super-editor, administrador \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Precondiciones: Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack[l]{
                Procedimiento:\\
                1. Usuario: visita xxxxx\\
                2. Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. \\
                3. Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio $\to$ taxonomías. \\
                4. Usuario: clica en el botón eliminar de la taxonomía deseada dentro de un listado. \\
                5. Sistema: cambia el campo eliminado de la taxonomía a True en la base de datos.\\
                6. Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error).
            }
        } \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack[l]{Extensiones: -}} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
        \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | }
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{UC18. Aprobar contenidos} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Objetivo} & Aprobar contenido (brigadista, encuadramiento o fuente) \\ & y guardar cambio en la base de datos \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Actor} & Usuario super-editor, administrador \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Precondiciones: Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack[l]{
                    Procedimiento:\\
                    1. Usuario: visita xxxxx\\
                    2. Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. \\
                    3. Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio $\to$ contenido \\ (brigadista, encuadramiento o fuente). \\
                    4. Usuario: clica en el botón aprobar del contenido deseado dentro de un listado. \\
                    5. Sistema: cambia el campo aprobado del contenido a True en la base de datos. \\
                    6. Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error).
                }   
            }  \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack[l]{Extensiones: -}} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The result of the code:

[image]

Comment: This can easily be achieved using `tabularx` like `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|}`. Maybe you should give a compilable MWE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenumi}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumi]{label={\arabic*.},nosep,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\newcolumntype{P}{p{\textwidth-2.\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | l | X | }
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|P|}{UC17. Eliminar taxonomía} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Objetivo} & Eliminar taxonomía y guardar cambio en la base de datos \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Actor} & Usuario super-editor, administrador \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|P|}{Precondiciones: Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|P|}{
        Procedimiento:
        \begin{tabenumi}
                \item Usuario: visita xxxxx
                \item Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. 
                \item Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio $\to$ taxonomías. 
                \item Usuario: clica en el botón eliminar de la taxonomía deseada dentro de un listado. 
                \item Sistema: cambia el campo eliminado de la taxonomía a True en la base de datos.
                \item Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error).
           \end{tabenumi}
        } \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|P|}{Extensiones: -} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \centering\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | l | X | }
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|P|}{UC18. Aprobar contenidos} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Objetivo} & Aprobar contenido (brigadista, encuadramiento o fuente)  y guardar cambio en la base de datos \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Actor} & Usuario super-editor, administrador \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|P|}{Precondiciones: Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|P|}{
                    Procedimiento:
                    \begin{tabenumi}
                    \item Usuario: visita xxxxx
                    \item Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. 
                    \item Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio $\to$ contenido  (brigadista, encuadramiento o fuente). 
                    \item Usuario: clica en el botón aprobar del contenido deseado dentro de un listado. 
                    \item Sistema: cambia el campo aprobado del contenido a True en la base de datos. 
                    \item Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error).
                \end{tabenumi}   
            }  \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|P|}{Extensiones: -} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

What I changed in comparison to the original code:

- Replaced `tabular` by `tabularx` in order to be able to use flexible width `X` columns for the second column to make both tables as wide as the textwidth.
- Defined a new column type `P` that is as wide as the textwidth in order to fit the `multicolumn` cells.
- Replaced the `shortstack` by a new defined `enumerate`-like environment `tabenumi` in order to alow for automated numbering, line breaks and indented second lines.

For a more open and uniform look of the tables, you might also consider removing all the vertical lines and replacing the horizontal `\hlines`s by fewer horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package. In the following example, I have also added some additional white space between the rows as a guide to the eye. Additionally, I have rearranged some of  the table's contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenumii}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumii]{label={\arabic*.},nosep,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}}

\newcolumntype{P}{p{\textwidth-2.\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{  l  X  }
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{P}{UC18. Aprobar contenidos} \\
            \midrule
            Objetivo: & Aprobar contenido (brigadista, encuadramiento o fuente)  y guardar cambio en la base de datos \\
            %\hline
            Actor: & Usuario super-editor, administrador \\
            %\hline
            Precondiciones: & Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador \\
            %\midrule
                    Procedimiento:&
                    \begin{tabenumii}
                    \item Usuario: visita xxxxx
                    \item Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. 
                    \item Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio $\to$ contenido  (brigadista, encuadramiento o fuente). 
                    \item Usuario: clica en el botón aprobar del contenido deseado dentro de un listado. 
                    \item Sistema: cambia el campo aprobado del contenido a True en la base de datos. 
                    \item Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error).
                \end{tabenumii}   
              \\
            %\midrule
            Extensiones: & - \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would prefer to have vertical lines, but I would use the second one.

Comment: I find a problem: it shows first the second table as first.

Comment: @albert: Latex orders floats such as `table`'s where it 'thinks'  they fit the best. For further information on the placement of floats, please refer to these questions and their answers: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/134144) and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `tabularx` or normal tabular with suitable `p{}` columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|p{4em}|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-4em-2\tabcolsep}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{UC17. Eliminar taxonomía}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ \hline
        \textbf{Objetivo} &  \\ \hline
        \textbf{Actor}    &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\linewidth}|}{Precondiciones: Estar logueado con rol super-editor o administrador} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\linewidth}|}{
                Procedimiento:

                1. Usuario: visita xxxxx

                2. Sistema: procesa la petición solicitada. 

                3. Usuario: accede a la administración del sitio $\to$ taxonomías. 

                4. Usuario: clica en el botón eliminar de la taxonomía deseada dentro de un listado. 

                5. Sistema: cambia el campo eliminado de la taxonomía a True en la base de datos.

                6. Sistema: notifica al usuario el estado de la acción (ok/error).
        } \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\shortstack[l]{Extensiones: -}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To me this yields an overfull box warning. It seems as if you are missing a `-2\tabcolsep` in the definition of the  columns.